# How to sort a list of objects ascending by a property, then descending by another property in Java?

Tags: java, sorting

I'd like to sort a list of objects ascending by a property, then descending by another property.

For example, consider the following list as `(age, name)`:

```
(25, Alice), (25, Bob), (30, Charlie), (25, David), (30, Eve)
```

I'm trying to sort it ascending by age, and then descending by name like following:

```
(25, David), (25, Bob), (25, Alice), (30, Eve), (30, Charlie)
```

I tried using `Stream.sorted` and `Comparator` to achieve this but I'm not sure how to reverse a `Comparator.thenComparing` without reversing the previous comparator.

Have a look at this example:

```java
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Dummy {

  private static class Person {

    private final int age;
    private final String name;

    public Person(int age, String name) {
      this.age = age;
      this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() { return age; }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return "(" + age + ", " + name + ")"; }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var people = List.of(
      new Person(25, "Alice"),
      new Person(25, "Bob"),
      new Person(30, "Charlie"),
      new Person(25, "David"),
      new Person(30, "Eve")
    );

    System.out.println(people);

    var sortedPeople = people
      .stream()
      .sorted(
        Comparator
          .comparing(Person::getAge)
          .thenComparing(Person::getName)
          .reversed()
      )
      .toList();

    System.out.println(sortedPeople);
  }
}
```

As you can see, I applied `reversed` to the comparator but the resulting comparison becomes

*age by descending, then name by descending:*

```
(30, Eve), (30, Charlie), (25, David), (25, Bob), (25, Alice)
```

But as I've stated above, the comparison I'm trying to achieve is

*age by ascending, then name by descending:*

```
(25, David), (25, Bob), (25, Alice), (30, Eve), (30, Charlie)
```

Comment: `thenComparing(Person::getName, Comparator.reverseOrder())`

Comment: in this specific case, you could have added a `.reversed()` in-between, like in `.comparing(Person::getAge).reversed().thenComparing(Person::getName).reversed()` - despite the solution from first comment is much clearer

Comment: Closed your question as a duplicate, but also added a community answer that's more specific to your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is creating a comparator that compares the age followed by the name, both in natural order, then reverses *that* comparator. You need to only reverse the comparison of the name, which is relatively straightforward to implement.

1. Use the [`Comparator#thenComparing(Function,Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)) overload. The second argument is a comparator telling it *how* to compare the objects extracted by the function.
2. Use [`Comparator.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder()) to get a comparator that reverses the natural order.

For example:

```java
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.Comparator.reverseOrder;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    var people = new ArrayList<Person>(5);
    people.add(new Person(25, "Alice"));
    people.add(new Person(25, "Bob"));
    people.add(new Person(30, "Charlie"));
    people.add(new Person(25, "David"));
    people.add(new Person(30, "Eve"));
    printPeople("UNSORTED", people);

    people.sort(comparing(Person::age).thenComparing(Person::name, reverseOrder()));
    printPeople("SORTED", people);
  }

  static void printPeople(String label, Iterable<Person> people) {
    System.out.println(label);
    System.out.println("-".repeat(label.length()));
    people.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();
  }

  record Person(int age, String name) {}
}
```

Output:

```
UNSORTED
--------
Person[age=25, name=Alice]
Person[age=25, name=Bob]
Person[age=30, name=Charlie]
Person[age=25, name=David]
Person[age=30, name=Eve]

SORTED
------
Person[age=25, name=David]
Person[age=25, name=Bob]
Person[age=25, name=Alice]
Person[age=30, name=Eve]
Person[age=30, name=Charlie]
```